# filter по дате, java script

Tags: javascript, json

не фильтрует, но выводит список, ошибки не кидает wtf

```
    const newsI = [
      {
        "id": 25,
        "title": "Yjdjcnm wewe",
        "description": "sit amet lacus. Aenean congue sem vitae nunc faucibus tristique. Sed dolor nisl, ultrices ac gravida eget, tristique id lacus. Morbi ultrices augue at leo",
        "image_news": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/IMG_1578.jpg",
        "slug": "yjdjcnm-wewe",
        "content": "<p>sit amet lacus. Aenean congue sem vitae nunc faucibus tristique. Sed dolor nisl, ultrices ac gravida eget, tristique id lacus. Morbi ultrices augue at leo</p>",
        "top": false,
        "publish": "2018-08-02",
        "updated": "2018-08-02T11:00:09.086848+04:00",
        "timestamp": "2018-07-26T13:22:33.559385+04:00",
        "user": 1,
        "section_rus": "Происшествия",
        "section": "incident"
      },
    {
      "id": 24,
      "title": "Новотсь 12",
      "description": "sit amet lacus. Aenean congue sem vitae nunc faucibus tristique. Sed dolor nisl, ultrices ac gravida eget, tristique id lacus. Morbi ultrices augue at leo",
      "image_news": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/IMG_1561.jpg",
      "slug": "novots-12",
      "content": "sit amet lacus. Aenean congue sem vitae nunc faucibus tristique. Sed dolor nisl, ultrices ac gravida eget, tristique id lacus. Morbi ultrices augue at leo",
      "top": true,
      "publish": "2018-08-02",
      "updated": "2018-08-02T10:18:58.360833+04:00",
      "timestamp": "2018-07-26T13:11:29.256174+04:00",
      "user": 1,
      "section_rus": "Экономика",
      "section": "economy"
    },
    {
      "id": 23,
      "title": "Новость 11",
      "description": "sit amet lacus. Aenean congue sem vitae nunc faucibus tristique. Sed dolor nisl, ultrices ac gravida eget, tristique id lacus. Morbi ultrices augue at leo",
      "image_news": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/IMG_1563_Msp6Ym3.jpg",
      "slug": "novost-11",
      "content": "sit amet lacus. Aenean congue sem vitae nunc faucibus tristique. Sed dolor nisl, ultrices ac gravida eget, tristique id lacus. Morbi ultrices augue at leo",
      "top": false,
      "publish": "2018-08-02",
      "updated": "2018-08-02T10:19:04.215084+04:00",
      "timestamp": "2018-07-26T13:11:09.350812+04:00",
      "user": 1,
      "section_rus": "Экономика",
      "section": "economy"
    },
    {
      "id": 22,
      "title": "Новост10",
      "description": "sit amet lacus. Aenean congue sem vitae nunc faucibus tristique. Sed dolor nisl, ultrices ac gravida eget, tristique id lacus. Morbi ultrices augue at leo",
      "image_news": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/IMG_1570.jpg",
      "slug": "novost10",
      "content": "sit amet lacus. Aenean congue sem vitae nunc faucibus tristique. Sed dolor nisl, ultrices ac gravida eget, tristique id lacus. Morbi ultrices augue at leo",
      "top": false,
      "publish": "2018-08-02",
      "updated": "2018-08-02T10:19:11.885819+04:00",
      "timestamp": "2018-07-26T13:10:11.625951+04:00",
      "user": 1,
      "section_rus": "Общество",
      "section": "comunity"
    },
    {
      "id": 21,
      "title": "новость 9",
      "description": "sit amet lacus. Aenean congue sem vitae nunc faucibus tristique. Sed dolor nisl, ultrices ac gravida eget, tristique id lacus. Morbi ultrices augue at leo",
      "image_news": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/IMG_1563.jpg",
      "slug": "novost-9",
      "content": "sit amet lacus. Aenean congue sem vitae nunc faucibus tristique. Sed dolor nisl, ultrices ac gravida eget, tristique id lacus. Morbi ultrices augue at leo",
      "top": false,
      "publish": null,
      "updated": "2018-08-02T10:11:40.182068+04:00",
      "timestamp": "2018-07-26T13:09:42.959838+04:00",
      "user": 1,
      "section_rus": "Происшествия",
      "section": "incident"
    },
    {
      "id": 20,
      "title": "новость 7",
      "description": "sit amet lacus. Aenean congue sem vitae nunc faucibus tristique. Sed dolor nisl, ultrices ac gravida eget, tristique id lacus. Morbi ultrices augue at leo dapibus, ut ultrices risus laoreet",
      "image_news": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/IMG_1581.jpg",
      "slug": "novost-7",
      "content": "Nam ut placerat sapien. Praesent vehicula rhoncus ante, vitae suscipit metus pellentesque nec. Phasellus eget neque sed turpis elementum ornare vitae id eros. Quisque finibus fermentum magna eu volutpat. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur feugiat scelerisque lectus quis tempor. Pellentesque nec odio in mi dictum porttitor id a quam. Donec fringilla arcu sagittis suscipit sollicitudin. Vivamus molestie lectus arcu, a tristique nulla semper ut. Nunc vitae sem eget mauris congue feugiat eu sit amet lacus. Aenean congue sem vitae nunc faucibus tristique. Sed dolor nisl, ultrices ac gravida eget, tristique id lacus. Morbi ultrices augue at leo dapibus, ut ultrices risus laoreet.",
      "top": false,
      "publish": null,
      "updated": "2018-08-02T10:11:51.963643+04:00",
      "timestamp": "2018-07-26T13:09:13.436177+04:00",
      "user": 1,
      "section_rus": "Экономика",
      "section": "comunity"
    },
    {
      "id": 19,
      "title": "I had the exact same problem",
      "description": "I had the exact same problem",
      "image_news": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/%D0%90%D1%80%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B72.jpg",
      "slug": "i-had-exact-same-problem",
      "content": "I had the exact same problem. The state was returned in the store but did not show up as props in the Scoreboard component. For me, the problem was with my action -> player.js.\r\nMake sure all the methods in player js must match all the bindActionCreator methods. Hope this helps",
      "top": true,
      "publish": "2018-07-29",
      "updated": "2018-08-02T10:18:18.867640+04:00",
      "timestamp": "2018-07-20T14:16:11.223530+04:00",
      "user": 1,
      "section_rus": "Экономика",
      "section": "economy"
    },
    {
      "id": 18,
      "title": "Астропрогноз на 21 мая",
      "description": "Бывшему главе района инкриминируют несколько преступлений",
      "image_news": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/1449210847155432089_vcZalHs.jpg",
      "slug": "astroprognoz-na-21-maya",
      "content": "gfdfgfg fg fdg dfg  hdhgdhhh h hghgh ghdhd hdfgdh hgdh dhgd h",
      "top": false,
      "publish": "2018-07-16",
      "updated": "2018-07-20T14:34:13.361464+04:00",
      "timestamp": "2018-07-16T21:06:40.725293+04:00",
      "user": 1,
      "section_rus": "Общество",
      "section": "comunity"
    },
    {
      "id": 17,
      "title": "Жители Заводского района жалуются на запах гари и дым",
      "description": "Жители Заводского района жалуются на запах гари и дымЖители Заводского района жалуются на запах гари и дымЖители Заводского района жалуются на запах гари и дым",
      "image_news": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/1449210847155432089_0Spogsq.jpg",
      "slug": "zhiteli-zavodskogo-rajona-zhaluyutsya-na-zapah-gar",
      "content": "Жители Заводского района жалуются на запах гари и дымЖители Заводского района жалуются на запах гари и дымЖители Заводского района жалуются на запах гари и дымЖители Заводского района жалуются на запах гари и дымЖители Заводского района жалуются на запах гари и дымЖители Заводского района жалуются на запах гари и дымЖители Заводского района жалуются на запах гари и дым",
      "top": false,
      "publish": "2018-07-12",
      "updated": "2018-07-16T21:06:55.402735+04:00",
      "timestamp": "2018-07-12T15:20:49.438655+04:00",
      "user": 1,
      "section_rus": null,
      "section": "incident"
    },
    {
      "id": 16,
      "title": "На груди погибшего около могилы мужчины была огнестрельная рана",
      "description": "На груди погибшего около могилы мужчины была огнестрельная ранаНа груди погибшего около могилы мужчины была огнестрельная рана",
      "image_news": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/1449210847155432089_PtAOaJv.jpg",
      "slug": "na-grudi-pogibshego-okolo-mogily-muzhchiny-byla-og",
      "content": "На груди погибшего около могилы мужчины была огнестрельная ранаНа груди погибшего около могилы мужчины была огнестрельная ранаНа груди погибшего около могилы мужчины была огнестрельная ранаНа груди погибшего около могилы мужчины была огнестрельная ранаНа груди погибшего около могилы мужчины была огнестрельная рана",
      "top": true,
      "publish": "2018-07-12",
      "updated": "2018-07-20T14:55:52.226080+04:00",
      "timestamp": "2018-07-12T11:48:42.859649+04:00",
      "user": 1,
      "section_rus": "Происшествия",
      "section": "incident"
    },
    {
      "id": 15,
      "title": "Саратовец: диспетчер скорой отказался присылать врачей к женщине с кровохарканием",
      "description": "Саратовец: диспетчер скорой отказался присылать врачей к женщине с кровохарканием\t Саратовец: диспетчер скорой отказался присылать врачей к женщине с кровохарканием",
      "image_news": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/1449210847155432089_pcEmq6o.jpg",
      "slug": "saratovec-dispetcher-skoroj-otkazalsya-prisylat-vr",
      "content": "Саратовец: диспетчер скорой отказался присылать врачей к женщине с кровохарканием\r\nСаратовец: диспетчер скорой отказался присылать врачей к женщине с кровохарканием\t\r\nСаратовец: диспетчер скорой отказался присылать врачей к женщине с кровохарканием\t\r\nСаратовец: диспетчер скорой отказался присылать врачей к женщине с кровохарканием\t\r\nСаратовец: диспетчер скорой отказался присылать врачей к женщине с кровохарканием",
      "top": true,
      "publish": "2018-07-11",
      "updated": "2018-07-20T14:55:57.760608+04:00",
      "timestamp": "2018-07-11T19:30:03.990959+04:00",
      "user": 1,
      "section_rus": "Происшествия",
      "section": "economy"
    },
]


      newsI.map((date) => {
        console.log('=============');
        console.log(date.timestamp);
        newsI.filter((news) => date.timestamp.includes(news.timestamp)).map((news) =>{
          console.log(news.title + '---' + news.timestamp)
        })
      })


  // должен мапить по 
 // дата выхода
      // список новостей, с этой датой
      // пример как на meduza.io
```

Comment: какой-то упопротый фильтр)) `(news) => date.timestamp.includes(news.timestamp)` почему includes? у Вас там массив?

Comment: ну да, я же нему же и итерируюсь, и беру timestamp, что бы сортировать по timestamp не?

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужна сортировка,поэтому нужно использовать метод `sort`,а не метод `map` который предназначен для преобразований.Еще ошибка в том,что на каждой итерации `map`,у вас дополнительно отрабатывает `filter` и `map`.

```
const filteredNews = newsI.filter((news) => news.hasOwnProperty('timestamp')).sort((a,b) => {
      return new Date(a.timestamp) - new Date(b.timestamp);
    });
console.log(filteredNews)
```

Comment: не нужна сортировка)) так как он мапит уже сортированный, нужна группировка)